# specify target URL using onelogin saml java toolkit

Tags: onelogin

I have downloaded `onelogin` `saml` java toolkit and its working as expected but after login it is taking to `developers.onelogin.com`.

Where can I set target URL to take the user after successful login?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml#settings?

You need to properly configure the IdP section. I guess that you used as 'onelogin.saml2.idp.single_sign_on_service.url' the developer site URL instead a real IdP SSO URL.